# JRebel with IntelliJ and buildr?

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel, buildr

I am working with a buildr project using IntelliJ IDEA and I want to get JRebel working. This is a Spring MVC project.

I have my rebel.xml configured and I created an ant script to re-package the application:

```
buildr package test=no
```

JRebel says it redeployed, but Spring seems to not be running after the redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do is to enable JRebel logging by adding **-Drebel.log=true** to JVM arguments and send the log file to support.

Do you see any messages in console that JRebel is actually started and is monitoring the directories? Maybe the license is missing?